# Express Js Setting a variable outside pool.query()

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to JS. I'm trying to set result value inside pool.query in express.js in code below and it doesn't work. I can't figure out why. Any solution.

```
var result = true;      
if (username) {
            pool.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM user WHERE ?', {name: item}, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (!error){
                    result = (!((results[0].count) > 0));
                }else{ 
                    result = (false);
                }
            });
            return len >= 4 && result;
}
```

Comment: `pool.query` is asynchronous, so it isn't running that function immediately, you're just defining it there.

Comment: I got it now. I'm trying to check username exists or not for making registration. How to handle these situation. Is there any way to make synchronous request?

Comment: You should not use sync functions in node, since it will block the thread

Comment: so how to handle these kind of situations? Is there anything like returning function after the result from database?

Answer (score 0):

Use an async function and write your logic in try..catch block.

```
async function yourFunctionName(){
    try{
        var result = true;      
        if (username) {
           var Results= await pool.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM user WHERE ?', {name: item});
           result = (!((Results[0].count) > 0));
        }
        
        return len >= 4 && Results ;
     }.catch(error){
          //do with error what you must e.g console.log(error)
          var result= false;
          return len >=4 && result;
          }
}
```

I saved the results in a variable- Results. With that, I can return database query result in the async function. I hope you understand how this worked.